# Searching for non unique values between two columns

Tags: sql, duplicates, unique

I have a single table with three columns, 'id', 'number' and 'transaction.'  Each id should only be tied to one number however may exist many times in the table under different values of transaction.  I've been unable to develop a query that will return cases of a single id sharing multiple numbers (and show the id and number in the report).  I don't wish to delete these values via the query, I just need to see the values.  See example below:

Here's a screenshot example: http://i591.photobucket.com/albums/ss355/riggins_83/table2_zps5509f3cf.jpg  I appreciate the assistance, I've tried all the code posted here and it hasn't given me the output I'm looking for.   As seen in the screenshot it's possible for the same ID number and Number to appear in the table multiple times with a different transaction number, what shouldn't occur is what's on rows 1 and 2 (two different numbers with same ID number).  The ID number is a value that should always be tied to the same Number which the transaction is only linked to that line.  I'm trying to generate output of each number that's sharing an ID number (and the shared ID Number if possible).

```
Test    IDNumber    Number  Transaction
1        31         1551    5
2        31         1553    7
3        32         1701    8
4        33         1701    9
5        33         1701   10
6        33         1701   11
7        39         1885   12
```

The result of output I would need:

```
IDNumber    Number
31            1551
31            1553
```

This output is showing me the Number (and ID number) in cases where an ID number is being shared between two (or possibly more) numbers.  I know there are cases in the table where an ID number is being shared among many numbers.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can see you tagged SQL but it might not hurt to also mention that you are talking about SQL tables here. "I have a table" is a bit general...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM thetable t0
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM thetable t1
    WHERE t1.id = t0.id
           -- Not clear from the question if the OP wants the records
           -- to differ by number
    -- AND t1.number <> t1.number
       -- ... or by "transaction"
    AND t1."transaction" <> t0."transaction"
       -- ... or by either ???
    -- AND (t1.number <> t1.number OR t1."transaction" <> t0."transaction")
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT IDNumber, Number
FROM YourTable
WHERE IDNumber IN (
    SELECT IDNumber
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY IDNumber
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT number) > 1
)
```

The subquery returns all the IDNumbers with more than 1 Number. Then the main query returns all the numbers for each of those IDNumbers.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e133a/2)

Comment: This query tells me cases of ids which occur more than once, this can occur many times and be valid.  The data I need is only cases where two or more numbers are "sharing" an id (an id should only occur next to one number however an id and number may exist many times with different transaction numbers).  I'm trying to find all cases of an id with more than one number attached to it.  thank you!

Comment: I've changed to `COUNT(DISTINCT number)`.

Comment: Here's a screenshot example: http://i591.photobucket.com/albums/ss355/riggins_83/table2_zps5509f3cf.jpg  I appreciate the assistance, I've tried all the code posted here and it hasn't given me the output I'm looking for.

Comment: Please update the question. Show the input data and the expected result.

Comment: Show it as plain text, or make a sqlfiddle. We can't cut and paste from screen shots.

Comment: I've updated the answer. I simply moved the earlier answer into a subquery, so that the main query can then return all the corresponding rows of the table. I don't understand why you couldn't extrapolate that yourself, it's an obvious extension.

Comment: Thank you for much the assistance, that works great!  My apologies for not making that link, I'm very new at this.  Is there a way to make the statement ignore case?  I have cases where the field "Number" contains letters as well, as a result the query output is giving me output for cases of the same "Number" being upper or lowercase.  For the purposes of what I'm doing if it's uppercase or lower case doesn't matter long as the actual value is the same.

Comment: In MySQL, use the collation setting for the table to indicate whether it should be case-sensitive or case-insensitive.